# Do .Exec or .ShellExecute wait for the specified process to terminate before the script continues?

Tags: vbscript, wsh, terminate, wscript.shell

[According to SS64](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html), for `.Run` you can specify `bWaitOnReturn` to choose whether or not to wait for the process to terminate before your script continues.

[SS64's details about `.Exec`](https://ss64.com/vb/exec.html) do not mention whether or not the script will wait for the specified process to terminate before the script continues when `.Exec` is used.

The [information for `.ShellExecute`](https://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html) also does not specify this important detail.

Do `.Exec` and/or `.ShellExecute` wait for the specified process to terminate before the script continues?

Comment: The two methods give different functionality, if you read the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ateytk4a(v=vs.84)) you'd get a better idea of how `Exec` works. It creates an instance of [`wshScriptExec` object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/2f38xsxe(v=vs.84)) that gives you fine grained control over the execution and monitoring of the running process and access to the various outputs (`StdIn`, `StdOut` and `StdErr`).

Comment: The same goes for `ShellExecute` please [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/shell/shell-shellexecute).